# How to validate if a User can Sign-In on Firebase based on email address or phonenumber list?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We have a collection on firestore (only authenticated Users can read the collection) with email address and phone number of our clients. 
We want to use Firebase Auth EmailLink and/or phoneNumber to authenticate them. 
We want only allow Sign-In for clients on our database. 
What is the recommended way to do this?

Comment: *We want only allow Sign-In for clients on our database* is a bit vague as if the user doesn't exist in Firebase authentication then they cannot sign in. i.e. you can only sign in and access data in your database is your user account exists. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide access to authenticated users.

You need to use this rule :

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

And make sure if user is authenticated with [Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users).

Something like this for web :

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```